# Proving that the $\sqrt 2$ exists with Pythagoras is valid.

Tags: geometry, functions

My attempt is applying IVT for the continuous function $x^2-2$ on $[1,2]$.

But I wonder that:

Does $1,1,\sqrt 2$ triangle prove that the $\sqrt 2$ exists?

Comment: What do you mean by "exist"?

Comment: Yes, it is actually the question that we need to ask.  For completeness of $\mathbb Q$ wit usual absolute value $|.|$ . But I don't wanna put any definition here.

Comment: IVT is good. Pythagoras requires solving $x^2=2$.

Comment: Your instincts are correct. The fact that you can construct a $1$, $1$, $\sqrt{2}$ triangle shows that this number is a real quantity even though it cannot be expressed as the ratio of two integers.

Comment: Why did people down-vote this question? Maybe I should have some trig-y integral question which most likes.

Answer (score 4):

The IVT is a theorem about continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ So if you use the IVT you are working with the real numbers and are assuming that $\sqrt{2}$ exists. You're assuming it exists in defining your triangle. I don't quite get your question. Are you asking if $\sqrt{2}$ exists in some platonic ideal? Cause that's more philosophical than mathematical.

To clarify: the IVT just says that your function must obtain every real value between two points. To say that $x^2-2$ obtains the value $\sqrt{2}$  between the points [1,2] by the IVT is only valid if we assume $\sqrt{2}\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\sqrt2 \in[1,2]$. So using it to prove that the square root of 2 is a real number is a case of circular logic.

EDIT: On further reflection I believe that the OP is actually asking whether you can use the IVT to prove that there exists an $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x^2-2=0$. In which case yes you can I agree. You can also use Pythagoras' Theorem to show that there exists some number $y$ such that $y^2=2$ by constructing a right triangle with adjacent sides of length $1$. You wouldn't specify the hypotenuse of having length $\sqrt2$ though, as that is just assuming what you want to prove.

Comment: But even if we dont know $\sqrt 2 \in \mathbb R$, we can also prove that $IVT$ is valid for $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @studentforever Check my edit

Comment: Here is the wiki proof of IVT. Is there any assumption of $\sqrt 2 \in \mathbb R$. I am disagree that we are assuming $\sqrt 2 \in \mathbb R$. (Don't misunderstood, I am asking this question for knowing and this is my idea. I can miss some parts but I am thinking that there is no such assumption).

Comment: No of course we are not directly assuming $\sqrt2$ is in $\mathbb{R}$ in the proof of the IVT, just as you don't directly assume that any number is in the reals. That's not the issue. The issue is that the IVT only makes statements about real valued functions, so if $\sqrt2$ wasn't in the reals you couldn't use the IVT to say anything about $\sqrt2$, as it would be out of its range of applicability

Comment: Maybe I will ask another question about this. I don't wanna make you tired here with my questions. Thanks for your answer and comments.